# matplotlib: default color cycle from style

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

Is there any way to recover the default color cycle used for plotting lines, which is somehow defined by the matplotlib stylesheet.

Since the `pie` function does not use the default colors, I would like to force it to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the color cycle from the rc-params.

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> color_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
>>> color_cycle
[u'b', u'g', u'r', u'c', u'm', u'y', u'k']
```

This can then be used as the `colors` argument to `plt.pie`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work easily with 1.5 as the rc params there contains a cycler instance and not the raw array.

Comment: Maybe then you can cycle through as many colours as you need for your pie chart.

Comment: The problem is that the cycle includes a property name. Some it seems I have to wrap some code around it to be usable again :/

Comment: I'll accept this anyway now since there doesn't seem to be any other way to achieve this.